# Spring Security SAML integration with ADFS - metadata.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-security, spring-saml

I've got question, becouse i'm creating Spring Security filter for application written in EJB3. I added spring security filter chain for this app. I've got configuration from spring-security-saml2-sample.war. It's working ok, but i've got problem with metadata.xml file, which is generated every page is loaded. Question is - how to export this xml file do ADFS 2.0 server, that IDP ( ADFS 2.0 server) will see. This metadata file is required in this section:

> Click Metadata information, select item with your server name in the
>   Service providers list
>
> Store content of the Metadata field to a document metadata.xml and
>   upload it to the AD FS server
>
> In AD FS 2.0 Management Console select "Add Relying Party Trust"
>
> Select "Import data about the relying party from a file" and select
>   file created earlier, select Next

I know that in example app we've got interface to generate this metadata for our service provider, but problem is with this, that in my application i didn't have this IDP selector - i'm using connection to default IDP. So, i didn't have possibility to export xml.

Is there any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks a lot ;)
Matthew

**EDIT:**

My metadataGeneratorFilter configuration:

```
    <!-- Filter automatically generates default SP metadata -->
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using auto-generated metadata or pre-configured metadata from a file in Spring SAML, you can download it from scheme://host:port/context/saml/metadata